# Monodevelop in Unity cannot find System references although Mono is installed

Tags: c#, linux, unity-game-engine, mono, monodevelop

I am currently trying to make a game using the Linux version of Unity. However, for some reason, when a Unity project is opened, Monodevelop cannot find the System, System.Core,System.Xml and System.Xml.Linq references, even if Mono is installed and can find these references when working on a regular C# project. I can write code that runs in Unity, but I cannot debug it because Monodevelop cannot find these references. I tried posting this in the Unity forums but I got no answer. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Linux is not fully supported. Why not install Windows on your computer? Make your computer dual boot....Windows and Linux.. Use Windows for Unity development and Linux for whatever reason you use Linux for.

Comment: This may be an obvious question but did you remember to include the System references in your Unity script?

Comment: http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/08/26/unity-comes-to-linux-experimental-build-now-available/ It is very likely that you hit one of the bugs in this test build, so use the dedicate Unity forum is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the System.Core, Sysgem.Xml and System.Xml.Linq assembly to your project references.

Hoping that Linux works similar to the OSX version, you should right click References in your solution window, and select Edit References. Add System.Core, Sysgem.Xml and System.Xml.Linq there.